# make two query work after each other

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to find out the names between a time period.

But the problem is when i try to run it

first-- it returns the selected names value
second -- it returns data between that period.

Now what i want to do is that, i want to search name between a time period.

**For explaining it more, suppose we have select a name "john", and select a date 2/08/2015 to 27/08/2015,
so it should return all the names between that time period.**

But it is returning the names of john and than searching for other documents between that period, where is should also take the name "John" when searching the date !

How to solve this problem !

```
    $name = $request->request->get('name');

    $strat_date = $request->request->get('strat_date');

    $end_date = $request->request->get('end_date');


    $params = array(
        'index' => "myIndex",
        'type' => "myType",
        'body' => array(
            'query' => array(
                'bool' => array(
                    'must' => array(
                    // empty should clause for starters
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    // add each constraint in turn depending on whether the param is specified
    if (!empty($sourceFilter)) {
        $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'] = array(
            'query_string' => array(
                'default_field' => 'name',
                'query' => implode(" ", $name)
            )
        );
    }

    if (!empty($end_date)) {
        $params['body']['query']['bool']['must']['range'] = array(
            'datehistory' => array(
                "from" => $strat_date,
                "to" => $end_date
            )
        );
    }

    // special case if none is present, just match everything
    if (count($params['body']['query']['bool']['must']) == 0) {
        $params['body']['query'] = array(
            'match_all' => array()
        );
    }

    $docs = $client->search($params);
```

But at always return the an error like this ----

> {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase
>   [query], all shards failed; shardFailures
>   {[agEfJ6ltSJmlec3gpnPg3g][myIndex][1]:
>   SearchParseException[[myIndex][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure
>   [Failed to parse name
>   [{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":{\"query_string\":{\"default_field\":\"name\",\"query\":\"john.se\"},\"range\":{\"datehistory\":{\"from\":1438207200,\"to\":1440626400}}}}}}]]];
>   nested: QueryParsingException[[myIndex] No query registered for
>   [datehistory]]; }]","status":400}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mix of `bool/should` and `bool/must` so you simply need to change `bool/should` to `bool/must`.

```
$params = array(
    'index' => "myIndex",
    'type' => "myType",
    'body' => array(
        'query' => array(
            'bool' => array(
                'must' => array(                       <--- CHANGE
                // empty should clause for starters
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

// add each constraint in turn depending on whether the param is specified
if (!empty($sourceFilter)) {
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = array(  <--- CHANGE
        'query_string' => array(
            'default_field' => 'name',
            'query' => implode(" ", $name)
        )
    );
}

if (!empty($end_date)) {
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = array(  <--- CHANGE
        'range' => array(
            'datehistory' => array(
                "from" => $strat_date,
                "to" => $end_date
            )
        )
    );
}

// special case if none is present, just match everything
if (count($params['body']['query']['bool']['must']) == 0) {  <-- CHANGE
    $params['body']['query'] = array(
        'match_all' => array()
    );
}

$docs = $client->search($params);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but i actually have tried that, but every time it returns me an error, i have update my question to show the error :)

Comment: my bad, sorry. I've updated my answer, please take a look again

Comment: Thank you so much, thank you so much ........ really really thanks a lot from the bottom of my heart :) thanks a lot :)